# Distributed client/server Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I want to use a network based computing to do the merge-sort on other systems.

I have a file on server and the clients should do the sort. Clients are different in process speed and response time.

I need an algorithm for "How to choose clients" and "How many of them to choose" ? Or even if this is better to perform on server only.

Comment: You need to search on Google for `load-balancing algorithms` like Round-robin,etc. for scheduling tasks to your *clients*!

Comment: State _what_ you "need" in a solution: Least energy spent? Shortest time to completion? Do you have a stream/queue of (uniform?) tasks, and are looking for highest throughput? Once you have your problem pinpointed, make the title of your question reflect that to get more views, if not a helpful answer. State what _is_ known about the resources: communications overhead (`response time`?), processing speed (specifying what? Time per conditional move?), interruptability, interference (e.g., contention in shared memory), …